# ASPX (asp.net) on WAMP

Tags: asp.net, wamp

I'm using WAMP and lately I've been working on files with the extension **.aspx**.
I'm trying to install the module for the wamp:  **mod_aspdotnet** but then I'm getting an error:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache2\ is not a valid path to an installed instance of apache.`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> mod_aspdotnet is a module for Apache HTTP Server 2.0.44 or later,
>   running on Windows, Windows NT Service Pack 6 or later (including
>   2000, 2003, XP and Vista) **with the .NET Framework 1.1** (or 1.0),
>   including Microsoft's ASP.NET hosting framework.
>
> It was originally developed by Covalent Technologies, lived for a time
>   at the Apache Software Foundation and is now maintained by the
>   mod-aspdotnet project hosted on SourceForge and sponsored by Covalent
>   Technologies. **It is not known to work on non-Windows platforms, with**
>   ***earlier versions of Apache, or 2.0 and later versions of the .NET**
>   ***framework.*** Consult the project's pages for more details.

http://mod-aspdotnet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Well.. I'm having Windows 7 Professional 64bit, I already installed the .NET Framework 1.1 and i still got this error